# Focus a field when the enter button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i've had a bit of help and I'm nearly there but I was wondering if its possible to have a field focus when I hit enter assuming I'm in a specific field.

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/xT5X5/2/

To get it to focus on the "current" field when I hit enter in an "accepted" field. This can be seen if you first add something, and then click on the field that is added and hit enter. I tried this code without much luck:

```
$(".accepted").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(".current").focus();
    }
});
```

Also, I was wondering if there is a better way of adding these "enter" commands into my code, because it seems like there could be a better way.

Comment: And what's wrong with the code you showed?

Comment: .current is a class name and there are multiple fields with that class. If you want to focus a specific field, you might give a unique ID to that field and focus via id $('#myfield').focus()

Comment: @daghan or use some transversal DOM method to target specific element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
$(".accepted").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(".current").focus();
    }
});
```

with:

```
$(document).on("keyup",".accepted",function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
         $(this).closest('.copies').next().find(".current").focus();
    }
});
```

Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xT5X5/6/)

Comment: this will focus always the same .current element

Comment: Yes, thank you that works but it picks the wrong element to focus on http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/xT5X5/5/

Comment: @roasted: actually, he needs something like $(this).parent().find(".current").focus();

Comment: i'd say $(this).closest('.copies').next()... but yes, you are correct it is just OP's code is quite unreadable imo

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are setting up the keyup event on page load and then dynamically creating the textbox's - the result is the textbox's are not bound to any event.

So you have 2 options add onClick="" to the textbox's or move the bind under the creation like so.

http://jsfiddle.net/xT5X5/4/

```
            $(html).appendTo(container);

            $(".accepted").keyup(function(e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    $(".current").focus();
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the part of code you copied to this:

```
$('.form').on('keyup', '.accepted', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var line = $(this).parent(); // this targets '.line'
        //this targets line's "container", which is '.copy', then find all the .current's in the next node (.line)
        var current = $(line).parent().next().find('.current');

        //as var current returns a list with all the .current's found, even if there's only one, it returns an array of elements in case there were more, so we select the first one from the array
        current = $(current)[0];
        $(current).focus();
    }
});
```

Explanation:
As .accepted is a class that is created after the document load, it's not existing when you bind the keyup function

You need to use on() instead, targeting '.accepted',

I have split down how to find the '.current' you want so you understand it, but you can reach it in several ways actually. I used the one I thought it would be easier to understand, here is a link to a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QaHB3/1/